# mysql wont start post install OSX El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan, mysql.sock

Im trying to get mysql running on my OSX machine.

I downloaded the DMG from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
After downloading I go to Preferences -> MySQL -> Start MySQL Server. It will wait for a couple seconds and then go back to "The MySQL Server Instance is stopped"

when i go to the terminal I try starting the server with mysld.server start but the command is not recognised "service mysqld start" yields the same result

mysql -version yields ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

the mysql.sock file doesn't exist at this locationnor does it exist at /tmp. Ive read that it should be created when you start the server but I cant start it therefore it cant be created.

I get the same problem when I try installing via home brew.

Appreciate advice folks can provide.

Comment: try to start mysqld and look at the output in terminal. you can also try mysqld --user=mysql

Comment: Thanks Bernd, here are snippets of the outputs ...... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/ChrisGualoosMBP.default.pid).

Comment: [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'

Comment: Please post the first line with ERROR. it looks that is the last ine

Comment: have you started mysqld as root # ?

Comment: I believe i have, mysqld user=root?

Comment: no, from root: sudo su        , # mysqld --user=mysql   OR # mysqld --user=root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104214/discussion-between-mogoli-and-bernd-buffen).

Comment: ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'
I did cd / the sudo su then mysqld --user=root

Comment: we have change to MariaDB 10.1.11 and it works fine.

Comment: in this version you can also use it in a DB Cluster. its direct includet Galera MariaDB